# SetWinEventHook not capturing any events in Rust application

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, hook

I'm trying to make application with Rust that counts time spent within specific window.
And now I'm stuck with Windows hooks.

I tried to use `windows` crate to setup hooks, where I could not make `SetWindowsHookExW` to work, because it was not allowing to pass null ptr as `hmod` argument. And `SetWindowsHookW` compiles but always returns `0` and that's it.
Now I switched to `winapi` crate, using `SetWinEventHookExW` retunrs something like `0x00000000` which I think is not successful operation. And `SetWinEventHook` when called returns seemingly normal value, but events are not captured for reason I can't figure out. Here is my current code:

```
// dependencies imports
...

thread_local! {
    static TX: OnceCell<Sender<RawWindowEvent>>= OnceCell::new()
}

extern "system" fn win_event_hook_callback(
    child_id: HWINEVENTHOOK,
    hook_handle: DWORD,
    event_id: HWND,
    window_handle: LONG,
    object_id: LONG,
    thread_id: DWORD,
    timestamp: DWORD,
) -> () {
    println!("EVENT?");
    TX.with(|f| {
        let tx = f.get().unwrap();
        let event = RawWindowEvent {
            child_id,
            hook_handle,
            event_id,
            window_handle,
            object_id,
            thread_id,
            timestamp,
        };
        println!("{:#?}", &event);
        tx.send(event);
    });
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<RawWindowEvent>();

    match TX.with(|f| f.set(tx)) {
        Err(err) => panic!("{:#?}", err),
        _ => (),
    };

    unsafe {
        let hook = SetWinEventHook(
            0x0003,
            0x0003,
            ptr::null_mut(),
            Some(win_event_hook_callback),
            0,
            0,
            0,
        );
        println!("{:#?}", hook);

        loop {
            let event = rx.recv().unwrap();
            println!("{:#?}", event);
        }

        UnhookWinEvent(hook);
    }
}



#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct RawWindowEvent {
    pub child_id: HWINEVENTHOOK,
    pub hook_handle: DWORD,
    pub event_id: HWND,
    pub window_handle: LONG,
    pub object_id: LONG,
    pub thread_id: DWORD,
    pub timestamp: DWORD,
}
```

Comment: [`SetWinEventHook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook): *"The client thread that calls `SetWinEventHook` must have a message loop in order to receive events."*

Comment: That means that I must do all this jobs in `std::thread::spawn()`? When I put all stuff inside except channel creation, I get 2 errors:

   
`*mut HWINEVENTHOOK__` cannot be sent between threads safely
within `RawWindowEvent`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut HWINEVENTHOOK__`
required for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<RawWindowEvent>` to implement `Send`

    

`*mut HWND__` cannot be sent between threads safely
within `RawWindowEvent`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut HWND__`
required for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<RawWindowEvent>` to implement `Send`

Comment: So I got rid of this errors by removing `child_id` and `event_id` from `RawWindowEvent`, it compiles but still doesn't work =(

Comment: You don't need MPSC on Windows to implement asynchronous operations. This sounds a lot like you're trying to solve problems going by "best practices". Those "best practices" predominantly cater to systems that don't know how to solve asynchronous operations without multithreading. Linux being the poster child example of a popular kernel that doesn't.

Comment: Just started diving into topic recently, and found this kind of solution in `wineventhook-rs` crate which I tried to reproduce. But there thread is organised in async way actually. Now I know another direction to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several questions here, so let's quickly cover those that aren't actually relevant up front:

> I could not make `SetWindowsHookExW` to work, because it was not allowing to pass null ptr as `hmod` argument.

The signature for [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.SetWindowsHookExW.html) in the `windows` crate expects a type that implements `IntoParam<HMODULE>` for the `hmod` parameter, which allows passing either a valid [`HMODULE`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.HMODULE.html) value, or `None` (which gets converted into a null pointer).

> Now I switched to `winapi` crate

You shouldn't. It's no longer actively maintained and doesn't, to my knowledge, provide any functionality that's not also available through the `windows` (or `windows-sys`) crates.

> using `SetWinEventHookExW` retunrs something like `0x00000000` which I think is not successful operation

I don't know what `SetWinEventHookExW` is. I assume this is a typo, and should read [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) instead. If that is the case, a return value of zero indicates failure.

---

With that covered, [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) is the most appropriate system service to monitor foreground activation events, and `windows` is the most convenient Rust crate to access it. Regardless of whether you choose [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) or WinEvents, you practically always have to spin up a message loop (calling `GetMessage`/`DispatchMessage`) on the thread that installed the hook to receive notifications.

The following implementation (using the `windows` crate) sets up a WinEvents hook to receive `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` notifications:

*main.rs*

```rust
use windows::{
    w,
    Win32::{
        Foundation::HWND,
        UI::{
            Accessibility::{SetWinEventHook, HWINEVENTHOOK},
            WindowsAndMessaging::{
                MessageBoxW, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, MB_OK, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT,
            },
        },
    },
};

fn main() {
    let hook = unsafe {
        SetWinEventHook(
            EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
            EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
            None,
            Some(win_event_hook_callback),
            0,
            0,
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT,
        )
    };
    // Make sure the hook is installed; a real application would want to do more
    // elaborate error handling
    assert!(!hook.is_invalid(), "Failed to install hook");

    // Have the system spin up a message loop (and get a convenient way to exit
    // the application for free)
    let _ = unsafe {
        MessageBoxW(
            None,
            w!("Click OK to terminate"),
            w!("Event hook running"),
            MB_OK,
        )
    };
}

unsafe extern "system" fn win_event_hook_callback(
    _hook_handle: HWINEVENTHOOK,
    _event_id: u32,
    _window_handle: HWND,
    _object_id: i32,
    _child_id: i32,
    _thread_id: u32,
    _timestamp: u32,
) {
    println!("Event received.");
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```ini
[package]
name = "win_event_hook"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.48.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_UI_Accessibility",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
]
```

This is taking advantage of the fact, that the system will dispatch messages on the calling thread as long as the [`MessageBoxW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) is up. Depending on application needs, you'd probably want to implement your own message loop. This doesn't strictly require spinning up an additional thread; [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjectsex) solves this by waiting for messages arriving, kernel objects getting signaled, or I/O completion routines/APCs getting queued on the calling thread.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and solves my problem

Comment: I both love and hate the `MessageBoxW` usage here.  It does the job for you (very elegant and minimalistic), but isn't _generally_ useful to solve this problem for most people, as they need to know how to set up such an event loop.  So it works for the demo, but isn't useful in production.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks for appreciating the minimalistic nature. The code provided here certainly isn't a production-ready implementation of a foreground activation monitor. It's merely an answer to the question ("Why don't I receive notifications?"). "How do I set up an alertable message loop?" is a different question. I just provided a single LEGO® piece. If you need to fit another one above or below it, there's the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button for that.